# Unexpected closing of a Stream while concatenating them

Tags: java, java-stream

Using Java 8 (if that matters), I have a behavior I struggle to understand.

Let's say I have an `Entry` class as such :

```
static class Entry {
    String key;
    List<String> values;
    public Entry(String key, String... values) {
        this.key = key;
        this.values = Arrays.asList(values);
    }
}
```

And a list of instances :

```
List<Entry> entries = Arrays.asList(
    new Entry("a", "a1"),
    new Entry("b", "b1"),
    new Entry("a", "a2"));
);
```

Now I want to collect all entries having the same key (and keep distinct values), and I stumbled upon a "IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed".

The minimal code for producing it is :

```
entries.stream().collect(
  Collectors.groupingBy(
    e -> e.key,
    Collectors.mapping(
        e -> e.values.stream(), 
        Collectors.reducing(Stream.<String>empty(), Stream::concat))
  )
);
```

(I'd add a `collectingAndThen` to meet my requirement, but it's not the point of my question)

I fail to see which part of the code consumes / acts on the streams. Furthermore, if I change the code to the following, it works :

```
entries.stream().collect(
  Collectors.groupingBy(
    e -> e.key,
    Collectors.mapping(
        e -> e.values.stream(), 
        Collectors.reducing(Stream::concat))
  )
);
```

I'd rather use the former code, because the later gives me a `Map<K, Optional<V>>` while the former gives a `Map<K, V>`.

But the question is : what difference does the usage of a neutral element does in the reduction, that ultimately causes (at least) one of the stream to be consumed ?

Comment: By *neutral element* do you mean the `identity` element? It ensures that you would certainly have a `T value` mapped and it cannot be absent as possible in `Optional<T>`. By the requirement *I want to collect all entries having the same key (and keep distinct values)*, are you not looking for `Map<String, Set<String>> map` as an output?

Comment: `Stream::concat` consumes the incoming streams. Since you specified the same `Stream.empty()` as identity element, this is a broken use of Reduction. In fact, even without an identity element, the implied consumption of the incoming streams is a modification of the input, hence, a violation of the contract. Which you can get away with, as long as no stream instance occurs more than once in the stream.

Comment: The main problem is you cannot have a stream as identity element because streams cannot be reused, so when it tries to reuse it, throws saying it is operated upon or closed.

Comment: @Naman yes, a `Map<String, Set<String>>` was the goal (I know a few different ways to achieve it), but I stumbled on this question along the way. And yes, by neutral, I meant the empty stream. I understand how and why it allows to remove the Optional in the result, I did not anticipate it could fail like it did, hence the question.

Comment: @Holger thanks. I did not know that concatenation was a consumming operation AND I failed to realiaze that the same `Stream.empty()̀` instance would be used each time a new key is met. That was a key point missing from my understanding too.

Comment: @GPI then you’ve learned something really important. The contract requires that `id op x = x` is always valid, regardless of what you assume about when it might get evaluated. E.g., when using a parallel stream, it might also get used multiple times, even when reduction is used without grouping. Using `flatMapping` would be preferred here, but even better would be performing whatever you’re intending to do with the resulting streams right at this place.

Comment: @Holger I understand. I *guess* what clouded my understanding is that an `id` such as `Collections.emptyList()` is safe for such usage, but `Stream.empty()` is not, which is (was :-) ) not that intuitive to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem can be reduced to this similar example:

```
Stream<String> identity = Stream.empty();
Stream<String> stream1 = Stream.of("1");
Stream<String> stream2 = Stream.of("2");
Stream.concat(identity, stream1); //works
Stream.concat(identity, stream2); //java.lang.IllegalStateException
```

In other words,

```
Collectors.reducing(Stream.<String>empty(), Stream::concat)
```

Creates *one* stream object with `Stream.<String>empty()`, and reuses it as the identity value in your multi-level reduction. Fortunately, you already have a workaround.

---

As warned against in the docs, and also pointed out in comments, repeated stream concatenation is discouraged:

> Use caution when constructing streams from repeated concatenation. Accessing an element of a deeply concatenated stream can result in deep call chains, or even StackOverflowException.

One alternative approach I can think of is to flatten the stream before grouping:

```
//This yields a Map<String, List<String>>
entries.stream()
    .flatMap(v -> v.values.stream().map(val -> new SimpleEntry<>(v.key, val)))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Map.Entry::getKey, 
        Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, 
                           Collectors.toList())));
```

Comment: [Not a recommended](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#concat-java.util.stream.Stream-java.util.stream.Stream-) workaround though: “*Use caution when constructing streams from repeated concatenation. Accessing an element of a deeply concatenated stream can result in deep call chains, or even StackOverflowException [sic].*”

Comment: Your reduction of the issue kinds of lacks a bit of context - at first. Sure, what you showed fails, but I would have guessed it. What I did not guess before asking was "where/why is any stream i build in my question re-used". I'd be happy to mark your answer accepted if you expand a bit on this.

Comment: @GPI - I possibly oversimplified it, but what you describe is exactly the point I'm making (or at least trying to). You have one `Stream` identity object in a multi-level reduction. I supposed that answered your question (which asked *I fail to see which part of the code consumes / acts on the streams*). About the accept, I'm sure there's still time for better answers to come, but you're also welcome to edit this answer!

Comment: @ernest_k I've edited in a way that would have been immediatly clear to me. Feel free to revert if you feel it's different from what you meant.

Comment: @GPI Your version illustrates the same problem perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is you cannot have a stream as identity element because streams cannot be reused, so when it tries to reuse it, throws saying it is operated upon or closed.

This is an alternative to the approach (returning List instead of Optional):

```
Map<String, List<String>> collect = entries.stream().collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(
        e -> e.key,
        Collectors.flatMapping(e -> e.values.stream(), Collectors.toList())))
```

Comment: `flatMapping` is nice but I'm Java 8 (I did not explicitely tag Java 8, so no worry). There are many solutions to chose from, e.g. creating a simple `Collector.of(HashSet::new, (acc, value) -> acc.addAll(value), (acc1, acc2) -> acc1.addAll(acc2))̀`, using a `CollectingAndThen(toList(), lists -> lists.stream.distinct.collect)`... The crux of the issue really was that a `Stream.empty()` is no more reusable as a `Stream.of(...)`, as you mentionned.